# LINQ Exclude records using 2 different database contexts

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I had some code that was working fine when looking at a single database context but when I split the models into 2 different contexts the query now fails.

So I get that I can't use 2 different contexts in a single query so I tried extracting one set into a list and then excluded entries in the list from the query

```
var exclude = _traceContext.TraceDetails.Where(w => w.Trace.CreatedBy == userName).ToList();

var data = from s in _billingContext.log
                   where s.FormattedMessage.Contains(userName)
                   where !(
                           from l in exclude
                           select l.LogTime
                           ).Contains(s.Timestamp)
                   select s;
```

This gets a conversion error:

**SqlException: Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.**

Both columns are `DateTime`

If I try and generate data as:

```
var data = _billingContext.log.Where(l => !exclude.Any(e => e.LogTime == l.Timestamp)).OrderBy(o => o.objID);
```

I get:

**InvalidOperationException: The LINQ expression 'DbSet
.Where(y => !(__exclude_0
.Any(e => e.LogTime == y.Timestamp)))' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to either AsEnumerable(), AsAsyncEnumerable(), ToList(), or ToListAsync().**

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here. What I need is the contents of `log` where none of the LogTimes are in the Timestamps in `exclude`

**Edit After using Contains as the comment from Mong Zhu**

So I still got the conversion error when using Contains so tried splitting the operation and making sure I'm comparing 2 of the same types

```
var exclude = _traceContext.TraceDetails.Where(w => w.Trace.CreatedBy == userName).Select(f => f.LogTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff")).ToList();

            var data = _billingContext.YWAF_log.Where(s => s.FormattedMessage.Contains(userName));

            var data2 = from d in data where !exclude.Contains(d.Timestamp.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff")) select d;
```

This gets me the **'your query could not be translated...'**

**Edit - Models as requested**

```
    public class Trace
{
    [Key]
    public int ObjID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }
    public string ServerName { get; set; }

    public ICollection<TraceDetail> TraceDetails { get; set; }
}

    public class TraceDetail
{
    [Key]
    public int ObjID { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff}")]
    public DateTime LogTime { get; set; }
    public string ServiceName { get; set; }
    public int Duration { get; set; }
    public int? Threshold { get; set; }

    public Trace Trace{ get; set; }
}

public class YWAF_log
{
    [Key]
    public int objID { get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm.ss.fff}")]
    public DateTime Timestamp { get; set; }
    public string FormattedMessage { get; set; }
}
```

Please note I can't match on objID as they are sequences and as the database is restored frequently they aren't re-sequenced.

Trace and TraceDetail are in one context and YWAF_Log in a different context - both DBs are SQL Server 2008 R2

Comment: What is the format of the datetime in the log file?  The log file is a string/text so you will need to parse the string to a DateTime.

Comment: entity does like `Any` you have to work with `Contains`.

Comment: @jdweng They are both DateTime

Comment: the method `Contains` will be traslated to an SQL expression like this: `WHERE x IN {..here are all values of your List..}`

Comment: How can a log file which is TEXT be a DATETIME object?

Comment: @jdweng it's not a log file - it's a TABLE in the database and part of the _billingContext

Comment: @MongZhu If I use Contains I still get the same conversion error - see the update above for more details :-)

Comment: for clarity: so you want actually to exclude items in the first context that have exactly the same timestamp as in the second context? and you would like to compare them to the precision of milliseconds? is that right?

Comment: if it is exactly the same timestamp down to the Ticks, then try please to remove `.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff")` from the Select and from the Contains query in your edited version

Comment: for your edited version i get a different error message: that there is no SQL support for the ToString method

Comment: @MongZhu If I remove the ToString(...) I get the conversion error - by adding the ToString(...) I was trying to ensure that the comparison was made against the same types. What I want to do it display a list of log entries that does not contain any log entries that have been saved - the datetime down to ms is the only usable value I have

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221880/discussion-between-mong-zhu-and-bhs).

Comment: Could you share your related model which could help reproduce the issue?

Comment: @Rena Updated as requested.

Comment: Hi @bhs,I tried you first way,it could work well in my project.What is your `userName`?

Answer (score 0):

change your code to this :

```
var exclude = _traceContext.TraceDetails.Where(w => w.Trace.CreatedBy == userName).select(c => c.LogTime).ToList();

var data = from s in _billingContext.log
                   where s.FormattedMessage.Contains(userName)
                   and
                     !exclude.Contains(s.Timestamp)
                   select s;
```

Comment: This gives the same error: SqlException: Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Comment: are you shore LogTime and  Timestamp is the same datatype ?